# Problems reading Bluetooth Device data and returning it into code in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

The following is the function code I am using to read the data from the Bluetooth Device

```
Future listServices() async {
  List<BluetoothService>? services = await primBms?.device.discoverServices();
  List values = [];
  services?.forEach((service) async {
    if (service.uuid.toString() == primBmsUuids[0]) {
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in service.characteristics) {
        List<int> value = await c.read();
        int val = int.parse(String.fromCharCode(value[0]) + String.fromCharCode(value[1]));            
        print(value);
        print(val);
        values.add(val);
      }
    }
  });
  return values;
}
```

I am parsing the character codes from the read data packet, however using this function returns an empty list. I used a print function to confirm whether value and val return valid values and they do, however for whatever reason these do not get added to the list.

Can someone kindly help me figure out the solution to my problem ?

Comment: Where does it return an empty list? `primBms?.device.discoverServices()` or `c.read()`?

Comment: When I return values at the end of the function.

Comment: So `values.add(val)`is never called. Could you add some debug prints to make sure you even find services/characteristics that matches your `primBmsUuids[0]`?

Comment: Well the print statement for print(val) returns what I'm expecting, however it just doesn't get added to the list.